# Transition my results from python to html file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I need to transition my results from python to html file. How i can do this. I used format function. I know about split html, hybrid of Python and HTML. Both metod cannot be use. My project is big and i need operate on variables to move results from many function to HTML report file.

The code below is a simplified example of what I need to do

```
def function(n):
    result = n + 5
    return result

def main():
    n = int(input('n: '))
    result = function(n)

    report = open('result.html', 'w')
    html = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>First Head</h1>
    <p>My result: ---> I need my result here <--- </p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    report.write(html)
    report.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: just use string formatting (a basic tutorial should cover that) or something like `string.Template` or `jinja2`

Comment: `jinja2` or any other template engine seems to be a right solution.

Comment: @Matiiss you are absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

So you want the results from that function in the middle? Not that hard um. Really no fan of multiple line strings with """ but here goes...

```
html = """
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1>First Head</h1>
  <p>"""
html += result
html += """</p>

  </body>
  </html>"""
```

OR you could make it an easier oneliner... with "{}".format():

```
html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n\n<h1>First Head</h1>\n<p>{}</p>\n\n</body>\n</html>".format(result)
```

Comment: I used f""" html code, {result}"", but my html code has many informations about bg-color, fonts. And python reads is as variable to format ;/

Comment: Now i`m reading about string.Template/jinja2 as @Matiiss said.

Comment: @KNapieraj yeah f-strings can f*ck it up sometimes, try the "{}".format()-alternative

Comment: @seldomspeechless no they can't and they are objectively better than `.format` except for support on versions <3.6 where they don't exist yet

Comment: @Matiiss if you say so, I've had f-strings fail and swapping to .format did the thing